# How to add pre defined text in getText() from Textview and show the result

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I have textview where user are asked to enter some information and that information is uploaded  in Firebase Data Structure and then is Displayed on another activity

Here is the code I'm using to getText from Textview

```
 etAuthor = (EditText) findViewById(com.nepalpolice.bookbazaar.R.id.editText1);
 String bauthor = etAuthor.getText().toString();
```

and it does job pretty well.

and it is added to firebase.

But what if I want to add predefined Text like

```
Author:getText()
```

Here I have added author.
and  This will be upudated on Database as well and will Displayed to user
instead of Consider Author is

J. K. Rowling

It will show

Author:J.K Rowling

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add static text both on client side or server side. Either append Author as prefix while displaying the data. Or while saving the data into database. It's a simple String concatenation. I am not sure what makes you worried!

Comment: could you help me with, How can  I do that...!! and Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Bir Nepali, you have to just append while getting the text.

```
etAuthor = (EditText) findViewById(com.nepalpolice.bookbazaar.R.id.editText1);
String bauthor = "Author:" + etAuthor.getText().toString();
```

Now you can populate this **bauhtor** in the view.

Answer (score 1):

you can concatenate the desired string, in you case:

```
String bauthor ="Author:"+etAuthor.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String bauthor = "Auther : "+etAuthor.getText().toString(); //use this, '+' use for concatenate
```